# ListView Inside Child TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, listview, treeview, wpf-controls, treeviewitem

Hey guys,
I have a WPF TreeView that has three nodes, I would like the last child (the third node) to contain a ListView populated with my bound data.  The issue that I'm running into is that if I put a ListView in the ItemTemplate of my HierarchicalDataTemplate I get a ListView for each child rather than a single ListView with content. This is expected behavior per the documentation, but I'm looking for a work around (possibly modify the ItemContainerStyle), unfortunately I have virtually no experience with the TreeViewItem's control template, or for that matter much experience with TreeViews in general.

I've looked at the posibility of using a TreeListView but it doesn't fit my use case, nor does binding a separate control and displaying data that way.

Has anyone either already gone through the headache of sandwiching a ListView into a TreeViewItem, or can someone suggest how to modify the ControlTemplate to accomplish this?

Thank you,
Aj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way to deal with the situation is to replace the HierarchicalDataTemplate on the second node with an Expander, set the ItemsSource on the ListView rather than the HierarchicalDataTemplate, and restyle the button on the Expander to look like the one from a TreeViewItem....sorta a hack but it works :)

Thanks for all the help,

Aj

Answer (score 0):

The node that has the Listview should be a different data type than the other two nodes so it can be handled differently by the Treeview.
Also it sounds like the child that contains the list view data should not be in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` but a regular `DataTemplate` one, since it doesn't have other child elements recognized by the Treeview. You can mix and match HierarchicalDataTemplate and regular DataTemplates in a Treeview as you see fit, regular DataTemplates represent "leaf" nodes, they don't have any children.

**sample with different data types used in Treeview but still using hierarchical templates:**

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FooNormal}" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeviewChildNodeCollection}">
   // do something else here.
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FooList}" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeviewChildNodeCollection}">
  <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding ListviewChildNodeCollection}">
   //use listview here
  </ListView>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hey BrokenGlass, thanks for the response...If you simply put a ListView inside a HierarchicalDataTemplate as the code you've supplied suggests, it will generate a ListView for each leaf node, not populate the leaves into a single ListView, which is what I'm going for.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should use different data types in the data that you use for the data context of the Treeview. You cannot expect different behavior if you cannot distinguish between the type of nodes. *Only* the template that you want to have the listview in should use the  "listview" data type (FooList in my example). Also the order of templates is relevant if the data types used are in a class hierarchy: Put the most specific data templates first, then the more general ones.

Comment: Thank you again...I'm aware templates need to be ordered properly and that the data type of each template is pertinent. I've got the rest of my TreeView working just fine...the problem is that a HierarchicalDataTemplate or DataTemplate within a TreeView wraps its contents in a TreeViewItem and regenerates for as many items as are in the items source, so if my leaf node had ten records I get ten blank ListViews rather than a single ListView with ten records.  Perhaps my implementation is messed up, would you mind posting the xaml where you've gotten this to work?

Comment: I actually found a good picture of what I'm looking to accomplish...apparently someone else tried, but never found a solution - http://i31.tinypic.com/21q44p.png

Comment: On a side note, this is something I'm sure I should have mentioned before this point (slaps forehead), my items source doesn't contain listviews it's simply a collection of text, I want to bind my collection to a single listview within the treeviewitem.  Perhaps that will help explain my problem a little better.

Comment: if you look at that picture it shows listviews for each leaf node, with different data, so is probably what the creator wanted. It sounds like you should massage your data structure to only have one leaf node with all the data, which would solve your problem. Also a "master detail" view might apply, where you have a separate listview that shows the "details" for the currently selected treeview node. Just throwing options out there for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it...I actually got a suggestion from one of the moderators on the MSDN forum - since the TreeViewItem is an ItemsControl itself to instead use an Expander as the templated parent...which worked like a charm...I just modified the expander toggle button to look like a TreeViewItem toggle, and removed the TreeViewItem toggle from the template of the parent's item template so as to remove the illusion of a double indentation.  It's kinda a hack, but it works, so I'm just gonna stick with it.  Thank you for all your help!